# Google Form Responses to Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-slides

I would like to import Google Forms reponses into a Google Slides presentation.

I've already looked at further topics to try to make it on my own, but I have an issue. Here is what I've already built :

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  
  var PRESENTATION_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
  
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(PRESENTATION_ID);

  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();

  presentation.replaceAllText('{{Nom}}', items[0].getResponse());
  presentation.replaceAllText('{{Date}}', items[1].getResponse());
  var image = items[2].getResponse();
  presentation.getSlides().forEach(s => {
  s.getShapes().forEach(e => {
    if (e.getText().asString().trim() == '{{Logo}}') {
      e.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(Array.isArray(image) ? image[0] : image).getBlob());
    }
  })
})};
```

But the main issue is that, in this case, the data isn't displayed on my Google Slides template (and of course the "XXXXXXXX" present in this code is completed by the real ID of my presentation, but I don't want to share it here).

So here, in this case, the data ins't displayed on my GSlides.

Answer (score 0):

**Bind your script with the actual onFormSubmit trigger**

This can be done [via the Apps Script IDE interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or through the code. For a simple trigger like that, I prefer the first way.

**Make sure the updates are pushed to the slides**

Normally, as soon as your script ends, Apps Script automatically pushes the modifications to the Slides. If you want to be really sure of that (or if you want to apply the modifications before the script has finished), you can manually call the `saveAndClose()` method ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose) - meaning the Slides is then closed, you cannot do other thing with it unless you re-open it).

**Share the Slides with user**

On a Presentation, you have a `addEditor()` method ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#addEditor(String))) to share the slides with someone. I'm not sure if it will also send him an email "a presentation has been shared with you". If not, you can use the MailApp service ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)) to easily send an email with the link of the presentation.

Comment: I have the following error message, sorry for not write it down before! TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined. At this line : 

var items = e.response.getItemResponses();

Comment: so your script fails before to try to update your slides. How is `onFormSubmit` called ? Have you set a trigger ? Your Apps Script is attached to your Google Form or your Google Slide ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My Apps Script is attached to my Google Form, and ideally would like that my onFormSubmit function is called when someone sent us the form.

(I'm so sorry for being technically so bad)

Comment: Have you followed this to setup your 'on form submit' trigger ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually It's only when this will be set that your code will actually be executed when a new response is made to the form

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much I didn't even did it before...I'm so sorry. Thank you so much for your help. It works! Last point for me : what should I do if I want my user to have direct access to the duplicated Google Slides (that it opens when the form is sent) ?

Comment: I'll try to recap that in my post ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clear. Just perfect!

Comment: I added a new answer to this post, because I've another issue, sorry for being that bad!